# Laravel 4.2 - Manipulating query string values before returning view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-string

I have a page that displays a product list. Each product belongs to a Section, which has various sub-sections, which have various categories and which, in turn, have various sub-categories. I use these properties to filter the products, and each of them only appears if the previous one is submitted (sub-section only appears if section is defined, and only the sub-sections belonging to that specific section, for example). I am using query strings to make my filters, like this:

http://www.website.com/products?section=21&subsection=57&category=92

As the user selects a filter in the page, this works well. First you select a section, and the page reloads with the child subsections. Then he selects a subsection, and the page reloads with the child categories, and so on.

My problem is: I want it to work in a way such as if I unselect the section, it returns the view without the query string, or at least with the other values empty. Currently it returns like this:

http://www.website.com/products?section=&subsection=57&category=92

I have tried returning the view only with a predefined input, like section, in case subsection is undefined:

```
if(isset($filter['subsection']) && $filter['subsection'] != '') {
        $category = new ProductCategory;
        $categories = $category->where('subsection', '=', $filter['subsection'])->lists('name', 'id');
        $view = $view->with('categories', $categories);
    }
    else {
        return $view->with(Input::except('subsection','category','subcategory'));
    }
```

This enters the else block, but the URL still gets all the query strings with their previous values. I have also tried `Input::only` but it yields the same result.

Should I do this another way, with a POST perhaps? Are there methods to clear the input before sending it back with `withInput()`? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use http middleware: http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: @Sarfraz middlewares were introduced in L5. In L4 there are filters.